# Haskell - function that sorts list with strings by integer value

Tags: sorting, haskell, quicksort

Below is my current code that sorts a list in acesending order:

```
qsort::[Int]->[Int]
qsort[]=[]
qsort(x:xs)
 =qsort[y|y<-xs, y<=x]++[x]++qsort[y|y<-xs,y>x]
```

How would i modify/create a function that sorts a list such as:

```
[("Bob",22),("Peter",38),("Charlie",19)]
```

by the int value

Comment: Your code would be immensely more readable with just a few extra spaces here and there!!

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the items in 2-tuples:

```
qsort::[Int] -> [Int]
qsort [] = []
qsort(x@(_,vx):xs) = qsort [ y | y@(_, vy) <-xs, … ] ++ [x] ++ qsort [ y | y@(_, vy) <- xs, … ]
```

Here you still need to fill in the `…` parts. The `vx` is the value of `x`, and `vy` is the value of the elements `y`. You thus will need to make comparisons between `vx` and `vy`.

Comment: thanks.. just trying to follow your code so the ... part filled in would be vy<=vx and vy>vx?

Comment: @John: yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible strategy. First, define a custom "less than or equal to" operator

```
lte :: (String, Int) -> (String, Int) -> Bool
lte (str1, int1) (str2, int2) = ...
```

Then, adapt your `qsort` implementation replacing each use of `<=` with a call to `lte`, and each use of `>` with the *negation* of a call to `lte`.

Answer (score 0):

for ascending

```hs
test = sortBy (compare `on` snd) [("Bob",22),("Peter",38),("Charlie",19)]
```

for descending

```hs
test = sortBy (flip compare `on` snd) [("Bob",22),("Peter",38),("Charlie",19)]
```

alternatively descending,

```hs
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Ord (Down(Down))

test = sortOn Down [("Bob",22),("Peter",38),("Charlie",19)]
```